# email signature with logo using CID Embedded Images (Inline Images)

Tags: powershell, office365

Trying to build a powershell script to create an email signature for an office 365 email.  The signature will have the company logo.  The four patterns that can be used are:

1. CID Embedded Images (Inline Images)
2. Base64 Encoding
3. Attachments
4. Linked Images

number 3 is out, since every mail would have attachments.
number 4 was tried but outlook and most mail clients will not download external links for security reasons. 
We tried number 2 and it does work in some clients.  Office 365 isn't one of them....which leads me to the old school #1 option.
If we go to the Office 365 web portal and edit the signature you can easily add an image and format your signature, it uses method #1 internally.  The problem I have is that we need to create these email signatures for hundreds of thousands of email accounts so we MUST automate it.
You can set a users email signature with the powershell command

```
Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration
```

you have to pass in a string for the signature which can be a mini HTML file.  The problem is that we can't get a clean way to build a HTML file for the signature that includes a CID Embedded Images (Inline Images) since we have no way to know what the boundary value will be in the MIME message that gets created.  We have the base64 encoded value of the image but can't see to find a way to get it to embed. So it will work in O365 AND outlook and other popular email clients.

Any idea how to do this in code?  does not even have to be powershell... C# graph API maybe?

We are open to suggestions.. .

Thanks in advance..

-Ken

Comment: If you configure a user manually in the portal, what is the output when you run `Get-MailboxMessageConfiguration -Identity $user | select -ExpandProperty SignatureHtml`? Can you use that to configure the `Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration` parameters as needed?

Comment: It's not clear how you tried to embed the Base64 images using the `-SignatureHtml` parameter, but if you haven't already tried using the [data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML), try it and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you Langstorm, that was the missing link... I was able to see HOW MS does it (which is inline fyi) and just build it dynamically.. testing now.. so far so good.. thanks for the reference.. I could not find that in the docs for some reason.

Comment: @user1005246 could you provide a code sample as an answer below so others can learn from that?